# MVC data passing in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making my MVC application. I open my view with predefined parameters like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("PickGroupForHomework", "Account", new {subject_id = id, qty=model.qty });
```

And this works fine, the data `subject_id` and `qty` are passed correctly. However, my view `PickGroupForHomework` contains a form to fill, which is then validated. If the input is not valid, the window simply should reload with the data `subject_id` and `qty` as defined in previous view. I do this in such way:

```
public ActionResult PickGroupForHomework(PickGroupForHomeworkViewModel model)
        {
            ClassDeclarationsDBEntities2 entities = new ClassDeclarationsDBEntities2();
            model.groups = entities.Groups.ToList();
            model.users = entities.Users.ToList();
            int id = model.subject_id;
            var subj = entities.Subjects
                    .Where(b => b.class_id == model.subject_id)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
            if (subj != null)
            {
                model.subject_name = subj.name;
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            return View(model);

        }
```

But the resulting URL does not contain the data I need, but just a plain view. How do I do it right?

Comment: Why don't you use unobtrusive validation. This would mean most issues are caught client side

Comment: Can you also show the View?

Comment: @KwekuReginaldWade see edit

Comment: Do you have this action? public ActionResult PickGroupForHomework()

Comment: Is there a reason you need the query string parameters when returning the invalid model?

Comment: @Jasen In order to display view correctly, it has to open with predefined `subject_id` and `qty`. It is a need and works when opening the window from a different view by `RedirectToAction`, but not when doing `return(model)`

Answer (score 0):

In order for you wep app to work, you will need two actions, one to set your model up for the View and another to actually do the work to post and save your data:

```
    public ActionResult PickGroupForHomework(int subject_id, int qty)
    {
        //Initialize your model here. Below is just an example.
        ClassDeclarationsDBEntities2 entities = new ClassDeclarationsDBEntities2();

        PickGroupForHomeworkViewModel model = new PickGroupForHomeworkViewModel();

        model.groups = entities.Groups.ToList();
        model.users = entities.Users.ToList();

        model.subject_id = subject_id;
        model.qty = qty;

        return View("PickGroupForHomework", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PickGroupForHomework(PickGroupForHomeworkViewModel model)
    {
        ClassDeclarationsDBEntities2 entities = new ClassDeclarationsDBEntities2();

        int id = model.subject_id;

        var subj = entities.Subjects
                .Where(b => b.class_id == model.subject_id)
                .FirstOrDefault();

        if (subj != null)
        {
            model.subject_name = subj.name;
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Save to database
            [code goes here]

            //return to a View to show your results
            return View("[Your view to see the results]")
        }

        //Model Validation did not pass
        //or exception occurred go back to View
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: When I open it moving from different window, it is `http://localhost:3449/Account/PickGroupForHomework?subject_id=2&qty=4`, but then, after wrong validation it gets `http://localhost:3449/Account/PickGroupForHomework`

Comment: Can you show the code for the Action ActionResult PickGroupForHomework(init subject_id, int qty) {}

Comment: There is no such Actrion Resut, since `qty` and `subject_id` are a part of `PickGroupForHomeworkViewModel`